# Creating a dynamic memory allocated string builder in C

Tags: c

One of the most painful work to do in C is to figure out the best and most efficient way to work with strings. Been searching and trying things for almost a day now. Anyways, basically, I was trying to create a dynamic string builder function, so here's what I came up with:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *alloc(void **ptr, size_t len) {
  free(*ptr);
  void *mem = malloc(len);
  if (mem == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "err: alloc failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return mem;
}

char *str(char **src, const char *fmt, ...) {
  if (fmt == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  size_t len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args);
  if (len < 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  *src = alloc((void **) src, sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
  vsnprintf(*src, len + 1, fmt, args);
  va_end(args);
  return *src;
}
```

And here's how I currently use it:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *s = str(&s, "FOUND!");
  puts(s);
  puts(str(&s, "NOT %s", s));
  puts(s);
  return 0;
}
```

While it does work, I'm thinking about things like:

- Possible memory leaks.
- And anything I'm doing wrong with dynamic memory allocation.
- As well as, how I initialize a `char *` with `str(&pointer, "value")` (if passing uninitiated `&pointer` is good or bad idea).

Is there anything wrong with the code and possible fix/improvements?

---

## EDIT

> Maybe I shouldn't have done this in the first place XD

Fixed according to answers/suggestions:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *alloc(void *ptr, size_t len) {
  void *mem = realloc(ptr, len);
  if (mem == NULL) {
    free(ptr);
    perror(NULL);
  }
  return mem;
}

char *str(char *src, const char *fmt, ...) {
  if (fmt == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  va_list args1, args2;
  va_copy(args2, args1);
  va_start(args1, fmt);
  int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args1);
  va_end(args1);
  if (len < 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  char *val = alloc(src, len + 1);
  va_start(args2, fmt);
  int res = vsnprintf(val, len + 1, fmt, args2);
  va_end(args2);
  free(src);
  if (res < 0) {
    free(val);
    return NULL;
  }
  return val;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *s = str(NULL, "FOUND!");
  puts(s);
  free(s);
  s = str(s, "NOT %s", s);
  puts(s);
  free(s);
  return 0;
}
```

What's changed (and notes (**N**s) for future reference):

- **N**: Passing uninitialized `&pointer` is wrong and is actually an error in disguise.
- **N**: Use `realloc` instead of `malloc` which handles `NULL` initial value and deallocates previous allocated memory.
- Changed `**` parameters to just `*`. The initial idea behind `**` is to be able to directly modify the `*src` pointer's value within the function (which somehow works in original code).
- Initial declaration changed to `char *s = str(NULL, "value")`, and updating the value needs to be reassigned `s = str(s, "updated: %s", s)`.
- Changed `size_t len` to `int` for `vsnprintf`'s return value. `size_t` is what I've initially used to match `malloc`'s `size_t` parameter.
- **N**: 2nd `vsnprintf` call might return different result after the first call, so copied the first `va_list` using `va_copy` for the 2nd call.
- `free` old string before returning the actual value.

Comment: To detect possible memory leaks I would suggest using Valgrind.

Comment: If this is working code then you probably want https://codereview.stackexchange.com for feedback etc.

Comment: `s` starts out uninitialized, you call `free` on it. I think this could be a problem.

Comment: You appear to have reinvented [`asprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf).  This is a GNU extension, but if you're willing to depend on glibc then GNU's pre-built, pre-tested version would probably be be better choice than your hand-rolled one.

Comment: @teapot418 I tried to run with Valgrind as suggested by @BRemmelzwaal, the output says `Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation` probably it's the `&s` pointer. Any idea how to change this behavior but preserve the original declaration?

Comment: `(void **) src` is plain wrong.

Comment: You could add an extra boolean arg to `str` to tell it whether this is first initialization or a rewrite of a string already containing something. Or do two separate functions `str` and `str_init`...

Comment: @Lundin I was thinking of modifying the pointer directly within the function. Guess I was wrong doing it this way.

Comment: `void**` is not a generic pointer type (unlike void*) so if you intend to use it like this, you need a temporary variable in between.

Comment: As for variadic functions they are good for many things: 1) Killing every attempt of type safety 2) Making your functions brittle 3) Creating confusing APIs 4) Complicate things needlessly 5) Enforce strange and unexpected implicit promotions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While it does work

No.  It fails in some subtle ways.

**Memory free'd too soon**

`str(&s, "NOT %s", s)` performs the `free()` of `s` and then attempts to read `s`: `alloc()` (with its `free()`) occurs before 2nd `vsnprintf()`.  This is a fundamental design problem.

**Indeterminant value**

Code fails with `char *s = str(&s, "FOUND!");` as `str()` eventually attempts `free(*ptr);` and the value of `*ptr` is indeterminant.

**Missing `va_end()`**

Code should always call `va_end()` after a `va_start()`.

```
if (len < 0) {
  va_end(args); // add
  return NULL;
}
```

**Advanced: `malloc(0)`**

`alloc()`, as used here, never calls `malloc(0)`.  Yet as a general purpose function `alloc(..., 0)` is possible.  In that corner case, `malloc(0)`, returning `NULL` is not a problem and code should not error out.

**Advanced: 2nd `vsnprintf()` may fail**

In multi-thread applications, the 2nd `vsnprintf()` may return a different value than the first.   Code could check the 2nd return value too, but we are getting into some deep issues.

**Wrong type**

`size_t len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args); if (len < 0)` is never true.  Check the return value of `vsnprintf()` by saving in a signed type.

Pedantic: `vsnprintf()` returns an `int`.  In rare implementations, `size_t` has a narrower range than `int`.  Should you care to cope with such:

```
//size_t len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args);
//if (len < 0) {

int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args);
if (len < 0 || len >= SIZE_MAX) {
```

---

Improvements:

- Compile with all warnings enabled.  That will save time.
- `alloc()` is strange to `free(*str)` and then not update `*str`.

**[Edit] Code needs to *free* after printing.**

OP wants to do `str(&s, "NOT %s", s)` which obliges `s` to remain stable throughout the print stage.

Code then must allocate for the new string, do the print and then free the old string.

`alloc()` appears to nearly act like `realloc()`.

Instead, return an error status and use `strdup()` (or a like function that handles `NULL`) for initialization.

Alternative untested code:

```
// Return error flag
bool alloc_alt(void **ptr, size_t len) {
  if (len > 0) {
    void *mem = realloc(*ptr, len);
    if (mem == NULL) { 
      return true;
      // or
      fprintf(stderr, "err: alloc(%p, %zu) failed", (void*)ptr, len);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *ptr == mem;
  } else {
    free(*ptr);
    *ptr == NULL;
  }
  return false;
}
```

With `str()`, consider updating `*src` even when `fmt == NULL` or `vsnprintf()` fails - maybe `free(*src); *src = NULL;`?

Comment: The maximum value of `int` *vs* `size_t` is not nearly so much of a potential problem as the **minimum** value.  `vsnprintf()` can, in principle, return a negative value.  The OP's code even tests for this.  But `size_t` is an unsigned type.  I wouldn't call that a pedantic convcern, myself.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Answer amended to alert OP that `len < 0` is a faulty test.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Can you check the updated code in my original post? I used the `realloc` now. Will it handle dynamic allocation properly for previous allocation? Or should I still manually perform `free` before allocating new memory?

Comment: @Yuriusu Code remains broken.  `char *val = alloc(src, len + 1);
  int res = vsnprintf(val, len + 1, fmt, args);` is bad as `args` still references the original `src` with `str(s, "NOT %s", s)`, but that is lost with `alloc(src,...`.  Review the answer: "allocate for the new string, do the print and then free the old string."  IMO, the entire approach needs re-work.  The solution others have done sometimes results in a new language. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions `alloc()` and `str()` seem fine.  You should maybe consider using `realloc()`, which could give you a small memory use/speed improvement.

You must ensure that you never pass an uninitialized pointer to `str()`, or your application will crash.  Any new string pointer should be zero-initialized before calling the function.  Why do you pass a pointer to pointer to the function?  You are getting the resulting string back, after all, passing the initial pointer by value  would help mitigate the problem, ex:

```
// expecting a pointer, not a pointer to pointer.
void* alloc(void* p, int len) {
    void* result;
    result = realloc(p, len);
    if (!result) {
        free(p);
        exit(1);
    }
    return result;
}


char *str(char *src, const char *fmt, ...) {

    char* result;

    // figure out len

    // ...

    result = (char*)alloc(src, len + 1);

    // fill the result string

    // ...

    return result;
}

// now str() can also be called as:

// ...

char* s;

s = str(NULL, "hello %s", "Mike");

// ...

free(s);
```

You are right to worry about memory leaks.  Every single string you create using `str()` MUST be deallocated using `free()`.

Comment: "You must ensure that you never pass an uninitialized pointer to str()." Doesn't the first line of `main` do just that?

Comment: I am answering point 3 of the original question: " As well as, how I initialize a char * with str(&pointer, "value") (if passing uninitiated &pointer is good or bad idea).".

Comment: How about a separate function for `realloc`? 'cause I plan to reuse the `alloc` function to avoid multiple error handling. Should I just declare the parameter as `void *` instead of `void **` in `alloc`?

Comment: Yes, as shown in edited answer.

Comment: @teapot418, the first line of `main` exactly *does* pass (the address of) an uninitialized pointer ovbect (`s`) to function `str()`.  `s` is later initialized with the function's return value, but at the time of the call, its value is indeterminate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  Answering hypothetical question from OP.  see comment #2.